# Data warehouse, SSAS

Tags: ssas, cubes, warehouse

I have been given population data like this;

```
Year      Region       Population
----------------------------------
2012     District1       1000

2012     District2       1500

2012     District3       2000
```

Now I have to make a cube where a user can filter population in Month, Quarter and Year level. So I decided to enter data into a fact table with each and every month of the given year that means 12 records for each District with the same given number. So if a user asks for any month he will get the same count. But now the problem is if user does not filter it by Month, Quarter and Year I get the Sum of all the data that means District1 will display 12 times 1000 = 12000. How can I get 1000 for district1 at any given time? If data is in multiple years then also it should not sum them up. Is my approach wrong? Hope I am clear enough to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your fact is a semi additive measure, more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175356.aspx